# What patterns could I implement in microservice development?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I'm going to begin a new project of microservice and want know about patterns that I might wan't to implement on my new microservice for that I could scale, don't have problems with load balance, have an good service with resilience.

> I looking to know about patterns that might microservices should implement

Also could you provide some indications for Java microservices application?

Answer (score 2):

**For solve some problems that was said:**  [1]

- Architecture: You could build small microservices as it can be, so that the scale be right focused on need to be.
- You could set a Discovery service for registering the applications instances, with that making easier to the client access the right application when are lots of instances of the same service (Netflix Eureka / Spring Cloud).
- You could set a Configuration outside the code source of the code, so that all the instances can be configured without human intervention right on the running code (Spring Cloud Config).
- Set a way the check the health of the microservice with ease.
- I circuit breaker for clear the anomalies microservices instances (Spring Cloud / Netflix Hystrix).

> and following as say the [Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/).

With lots of another things that you need to that care when building a microservice, suggesting the reading the book, if you'll use Java for building microservices [Spring Microservices in Action By John Carnell](https://www.amazon.com.br/Spring-Microservices-Action-John-Carnell/dp/1617293989) , if you i'll implement in another programming language this other could guide you, [Microservices in Action by Morgan Bruce and Paulo Pereira](https://www.amazon.com.br/Microservices-Action-Morgan-Bruce/dp/1617294454).

[1] (https://www.amazon.com.br/Spring-Microservices-Action-John-Carnell/dp/1617293989